# Business Intelligence : Data warehouse creation (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, database-metadata

I am working on a business intelligence module. Since I don't have metadata to create my data warehouse , Is it possible to find a script or any other solution to create that metadata from a simple 2 dimensions database ? 
PS: I'am using ORACLE database

Comment: Do you mean, a script that looks at a source database, and works out what a dimensional model would look like for it, and makes a script for creating that dimensionally modelled data warehouse?

Comment: Yes , exactly that's what I need